# The above error occurred in the </static/media/igesticon.731bb908.svg> component

Tags: react-native, svg, expo, react-native-svg

I have a bug that has been giving me a lot of headaches, I intend to put .svg images into my project and I have tried several ways although it always gives me an error... I am using the lib react-native-svg and I am doing it the following way:

Error: The above error occurred in the </static/media/igesticon.731bb908.svg> component:
in /static/media/igesticon.731bb908.svg

**MedicationScreen**

```
import React from 'react'
import { View, Text, FlatList, StyleSheet, Dimensions } from 'react-native'
import Logo from "../../assets/igesticon.svg";


const MedicationScreen = () => {
  return(
      <View>
          <Logo width={120} height={40} />
      </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: You cannot import an svg like that, try using something like `react-native-svg`

Comment: what is an `above error`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can embed SVG the following way:

```
const MedicationScreen = () => {
  return(
      <View>
          <svg width={120} height={40} >
            <image href="../../assets/igesticon.svg" />
          </svg>
      </View>
  )
}
```

See how it works in the snippet below:

```html
<svg width="64" height="64" viewBox="30 0 200 200">
  <image href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/he/a/a7/React-icon.svg"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely, you can't import svg like that.

You can use badass packages like [SVGR](https://react-svgr.com/docs/next/).
This package will auto transforms your svg to react component.

And you can use like this

```
import Star from './star.svg'

const Example = () => (
  <div>
    <Star />
  </div>
)
```

Comment: Actually, you _can_ import SVG like that, if you intend to use it with an IMG tag.